# Limitation of number posts on API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limits

I want to build a FB app which posts messages to the walls of those registered for the app.
There are two setups:

1. One message to many people (1-many, could occur few times a day)
2. Many user-specific massages (1-1, but many of them, could occur few times a day for each user)

All in all; one user could get a few different updates on his wall per day, but it could affect many users (that's pretty much the whole point of my idea)
Into what extend is Facebook going to allow me to do this, and won't think I'll be spamming.

PS:
I've come along this post, which seems to have remained unsolved...:
[Post on Multiple Friend's Wall](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6105907/post-on-multiple-friends-wall)

And this post, which doesn't make it clear for me whether my idea is something I should start or not ;)
[Graph API post to wall limitation](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8251654/graph-api-post-to-wall-limitation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Facebook batch API to do what you intent.

You can get more information on Facebook batch request at: http://25labs.com/tutorial-post-to-multiple-facebook-wall-or-timeline-in-one-go-using-graph-api-batch-request/

```
$batchPost[] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => "/{ID1}/feed?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_ID1}",
    'body' => http_build_query($body) );
$batchPost[] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => "/{ID2}/feed?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_ID2}",
    'body' => http_build_query($body) );
$batchPost[] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => "/{ID3}/feed?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_ID3}",
    'body' => http_build_query($body) );

$multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
```

Comment: I hadn't seen the Batch APi before, great feature! According to [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) its limit currently is 50. Say I've got 1.000 different users, I'll have to spread the posting over 20 requests (with short 'interval' as possible). Can this become an issue?

Comment: I don't think it will be an issue.. You can use 20 requests to post to 1000 users.. But always remember not to spam users.. In the blog post that I mentioned you can you can find more information on the issue. Actually the script in the post does multiple batch API call to post to 50+ friends.

Comment: In my case, all the users are not (nescasarily) related to eachother. I'll just have to post to a bunch of different ID's. According to [this forum post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56950) you can make 600 calls in 600 seconds (as they write back in 2010/2011). So that means in theory one is able to make 50*600 = 30000 posts in 10 minutes...gosh!

Comment: The users need not be related to each other.. access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_ID1} is used because of that.. If the users were related to each other then there is no need to explicitly provide access token for each call..

Answer (score 0):

I developed an app in my website http://www.cefozyt.com which can post links, message etc. to multiple facebook users wall & groups. I used :-

if($user){
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who has a valid session.

//========= Batch requests over the Facebook Graph API using the PHP-SDK ========
    // Save your method calls into an array
    $queries = array(
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/groups'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/likes'),
        );

```
// POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
try{
    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
}catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}

//Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in ['body'] as a JSON
//string. Decode for use as a PHP array.
$user_info      = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
$friends_list   = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
$groups         = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
$pages          = json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE);
```

//========= Batch requests over the Facebook Graph API using the PHP-SDK ends =====

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_x'])){
    if($_POST['message'] || $_POST['link'] || $_POST['picture']) {
        $body = array(
            'message'       => $_POST['message'],
            'link'          => $_POST['link'],
            'picture'       => $_POST['picture'],
            'name'          => $_POST['name'],
            'caption'       => $_POST['caption'],
            'description'   => $_POST['description'],
            );

        $batchPost=array();

        $i=1;
        $flag=1;
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if(strpos($key,"id_") === 0) {
                $batchPost[] = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => "/$value/feed", 'body' => http_build_query($body));
                if($i++ == 50) {
                    try{
                        $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');                          
                    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                        error_log($e);
                        echo("Batch Post Failed");
                    }
                    $flag=0;
                    unset($batchPost);
                    $i=1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isset($batchPost) && count($batchPost) > 0 ) {
            try{
                $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
            }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                error_log($e);
                echo("Batch Post Failed");
            }
            $flag=0;
        }

    }
    else {
        $flag=2;
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.